# Upload Image With Expo & Fetch

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to upload an image from my react native app.

If I use my local node server and run this code:

```
  var fs = require("fs");
  var options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "my_URL",
    headers: {},
    formData: {
      file: {
        value: fs.createReadStream("../../assets/image.png"),
        options: {
          filename: "image.jpg",
          contentType: null
        }
      }
    }
  };
  request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response.body);
  });
```

I have a succesful upload.

However, with the URI from that we get through the the app, it does not work:

Here is my code on React Native Expo:

```
 const body = new FormData();

  body.append("file", 'file:///path/to/file/image123.jpg');

  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body,
    headers: {
      "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response, "RESPONSE");
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result, "RESULT");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error, "ERROR");
    });
```

I am unable to get it to work. I think it has something to do with the file path from the device.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to create FormData using this function

```js
const createFormData = (uri) => {
  const fileName = uri.split('/').pop();
  const fileType = fileName.split('.').pop();
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', { 
    uri, 
    name: fileName, 
    type: `image/${fileType}` 
  });
  
  return formData;
}
```

if it doesn't work check permissions