# How to send formdata and image file in react native expo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, expo

Hi Everyone I want to send Formdata which includes some strings and an image file using react native expo  to node server and mongo db can someone explain how can I do this using react native expo I have tried several methods but I am not successful however I am able to send data using backend but I don't know how to send using React native expo?

Comment: look this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72046088/18341393)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the libraries you can use to send data from react native is Axios
you can install it via :

```
npm i axios
```

and here is how you can send data with that :

You can post axios data by using FormData() like:

```
var bodyFormData = new FormData();
```

And then add the fields to the form you want to send in case you can use append:

```
bodyFormData.append('userName', 'Fred');
```

If you are uploading images, you may want to use .append

```
bodyFormData.append('image', imageFile);
```

And then you can use axios post method (You can amend it accordingly)

```
axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "myurl",
  data: bodyFormData,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
})
  .then(function (response) {
    //handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (response) {
    //handle error
    console.log(response);
  });
```

related documents you may be interested in:
https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro

Comment: I have tried your answer but it gives following error  [AxiosError: Network Error]

Comment: that's because you run your node server on localhost, find your IP address on your machine then change localhost  to your IP Like Express.listen(8000, 192.168.1.1)

Comment: okay Let me try this and I will let you know

Comment: Node gives error as its not valid format

Comment: you need to handle everything in the node now that's a different topic